# Elastic Search Bulk API - Not indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have output a JSON file in bulk format which I can load in to Kibana with the developer tools. and by inserting a few lines using the -d command

example lines of file:

```
{"index":{"_index":"els","_type":"logs","_id":1481018400003}}
{"timestamp":1481018400003,"zoneId":29863567,............[]}
{"index":{"_index":"els","_type":"logs","_id":"30cee368073c0c9b"}}
{"timestamp":1481018400005,"zoneId":29863567,............[]}
...
```

However when I run the bulk api to pot a file it does not do anything. I added verbose to the command and get the following:

```
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9200 (#0)
> POST /_bulk HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9200
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 0
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< content-length: 165
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the curl command you're running?

Comment: I found the issue the bulk API is limited to number of requests in a file. I  split the files up then run the import and all works great